# what is the correct RAD model diagram

Tags: agile, sdlc, rad

I am trying to use RAD for our school project and i was searching for a model diagram to follow but i found 2

1st is the ladder type found [here](http://www.technotrice.com/rad-model-software-engineering/):

[image]

2nd is this one found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193488/is-the-following-diagrams-correct-for-rad-and-agile-methodologies):

[image]

so i'm really confuse as to which one i should follow here, also how will i assign my task in accordance to RAD model.

if i follow the 1st one 3 developers will do 3 task simultaneously as stated by the link above that ladder increment type model states that numerous software teams works in parallel on different system functions.

while on the other hand the 2nd option from what i can understand from the diagram user design and implementation "or construction" will be repeated until a satisfactory outcome is reached and thus it will proceed to the last step which is the cutover or "implementation", this too is what RAD or agile models are for to be able to adjust to change accordingly during the development period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both diagrams appear to be representing the same thing, but in different ways.

The boxes for "Communication" and "Planning" in the top diagram correspond to "Requirements Planning" in the bottom diagram. This is where you agree on stakeholder needs, scope, constraints, and develop the technical requirements that the team will deliver at Cutover.

The box for "Modeling" in the top diagram corresponds to "User Design" in the lower diagram. This is where you create your models of the system. The box for "Construction" in the top diagram corresponds to "Construction" in the lower diagram. This is where you actually write code and unit tests. The difference is that the top diagram clearly shows that you may have several iterations of modeling /user design and construction before what the top diagram calls "Deployment" and the lower diagram calls "Cutover".

Generally, what both diagrams is saying, is that your Deployment or Cutover - your final acceptance testing, deployment of the new system, and user training happens once in the life of the project. Your user design / modeling and construction activities may iterate - you can perform design and construction 1 to N times before you deploy the system. That may also include several subteams working on different features or subsystems independently of each other or the same team working sequentially on the user design and construction steps for features or subsystems.

Comment: so in simplicity the top diagram shows a more accurate steps on how RAD is implemented, while the bottom one shows the general overview of RAD that should be understood by those knowledgeable by it. and so it is really possible for RAD to have multiple teams in developing different functions of the systems or sprints which in the end can be integrated to create the whole system. I will use the bottom one. thank you, i was confused by this and thought that they are 2 different things, again if you could provide me with any links to help me better understand RAD it would be much appreciated